# clean reinstall of windows on dell xps 1530 using bundled software from dell?

Tags: windows-7, reinstall

i wanted to delete my laptop hard drive and reinstall the os that came on the media with the laptop originally.

i booted from the windows disk and reinstalled windows but this did not delete my hard drive and even worse it made a windows.old folder with all my old junk on my c drive

how do i get a clean/ deleted c drive with new install of my os?

i have a small 120 Gig solid state hard drive with just one partition. i would like to create two partitions on the new install.

my main issue is not being able to get a clean install such that the result is a pure windows laptop with no junk files that have accumulated over time.

please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/). Should do the trick for you.

Comment: ok i want to keep it simple so lets not partition and just remove everything and start from a clean windows install

Comment: Then you're at the mercy of your Windows disk.

Comment: @Jeffrey Taylor, DBAN, or another disk-wipe utility would be much simpler and basically do the same thing.

Comment: @Zoredache, I don't really consider Gparted to be much more complicated than DBAN. Frankly, DBAN can be pretty intense for a newbie. My recommendation stands.

Answer (score 0):

Download [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/), do a quick erase of the disks, which will overwrite everything with zeros.

Comment: after using dban will i be able to boot to cd and install windows?

Comment: wont running dban erase dban itself? can i get a link on how to run it?

Comment: Download the ISO, burn to a CD, boot it up.  On then menu choose quick erase.  Since it is on a CD, it can't erase itself.

Answer (score 0):

Even doing a clean install, you'll still have a `windows.old` folder as it contains folders and files from your previous iteration of Windows. It is possible to delete it, however, by typing in `Disk Cleanup` in the search bar in the Start menu.

Comment: During a Windows install, doesn't it give you the option of formatting the drive before installing the OS on it?